# How to increment (alter) a string for each passage in a loop

Tags: perl, loops, increment

AIM:

A tab separated file contains different strings. Some elements are identical, some are not. I would like to "concatenate" specific elements on the same line. However, in this operation I need to make changes to the specific element to separate them from each other, e.g. adding a number to the end.

INPUT (in **@input**):

```
File1 2 range-2 operation execute:error 12345444,294837,298774
File2 3 range-1 default range:error 349928,37224
...
```

I would like to concatenate the "field" execute:error with 12345444,294837,298774 and range:error with 349928,37224, to give this:

OUTPUT:

```
execute:error-1
12345444
execute:error-2
294837
execute:error-3
298774
range:error-1
349928
range:error-2
37224
```

PERL CODE:
I was thinking of performing a foreach loop on the elements in @input, using e.g. hashes to count the number of "strings" in last "column" separated by commas, and somehow add a number (e.g. equal to the total hash -1, making a counter?). But, this is a bit over my head. How, can I get this done? I tried a bit below, but have stopped after about two hours of trying and reading and searching for similar questions. Maybe I should not use hash?

```
my @output = ();
foreach (@input) {
    our(@F) = split('\t', $_, 0);
    my @end_numbers = split(',', $F[5], 0);
    %count;
    foreach (@end_numbers) {
        ++$count{$_};
        my $counts = keys %count;
        my $output = $F[4] . (adding a value here, e.g. $counts -1 for each loop itteration ) "\n" . $_;
        push (@output, $output);
}
}
```

SOLUTION:
After suggestion from @ikegami.

```
my @output = ();
my %counts = ();
foreach (@input) {
    chomp $_;
    my @fields = split(/\t/, $_, 0);
    for my $num (split /,/, $fields[5]) {
    ++$counts{$fields[4]};
    my $output = $fields[4] . "_" . $counts{$fields[4]} . "\n" . $num . "\n";
    push (@output, $output);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never have to use `our` save when forced (e.g. `@ISA`, `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK`)

Comment: I have made some changes to the part, thanks to your input @ikegami, and it works fine now. Thank you also for pointing me to the bad usage of 'our' in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are trying to concatenate is `$count{$_}`.

```
my %counts;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($class, $nums) = ( split /\t/ )[4,5];

    for my $num (split /,/, $nums) {
       ++$counts{$class};
       print "$class-$counts{$class}\n";
       print "$num\n";
    }
}
```

Or to save a line:

```
       printf "%s-%s\n", $class, ++$counts{$class};
       printf "%s\n", $num;
```

If you want the count to reset for every line of input, use `my $count;` inside of the outer loop instead of `my %counts;`, and use `$count` instead of `$counts{$class}`.

Answer (score -1):

Just use map function to prepend the string `$F[4].--$count."\n$_\n"` to every number in `$F[5]` spitted list

```
foreach (@input) {
    my @F = split(/\t/, $_, 0);
    my $count = 0;
    my @end_numbers = map { $F[4]. --$count .qq|\n$_\n| } split(/,/, $F[5], 0);
    print @end_numbers;
}
```

Comment: Note that this differs in behaviour from the OP's code. (Try adding a third line of input: `... execute:error 1234567890`)

Comment: @ikegami I don't see your point. You change the variable name from $c to $count, which is ok, but why you change it to increment instead of decrement? And dont see any problem with any number of lines, unless you are talking about ... be interpreted literally.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the cleverness of your code (doing arithmetic on something that isn't a number). So `$count` is not a good name either. Really confusing approach.

Comment: @ikegami but $count is a number, I just using that as an operand in a concatenation string operation. I am sorry you don't like it, but it works and nothing is wrong with it.